# Profiles disappearing?

Tags: support

What's happened to profiles? I find it useful as far as aiming answers at the right level to have a profile to go on. And on some sites, the geographical location is an important factor. Seems everything is becoming more secretive. Why?

Comment: I'm not having any trouble seeing profiles, on this site or on others where I'm not a mod. What OS/browser are you using? Can you describe what you see on, say, my profile? Whatever the cause, I'd bet it's related to the [recent changes to profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/388437).

Comment: Possibly related: [Link to own profile has disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368666).

Answer (score 2):

They are still there, however, as per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/154443) on meta.SE, they are being updated to allow for more responsive/dynamic pages. You can still find almost all the information that was previously there, it may just be a different route to get to it.